# How to get the pipeline Id of the current release in azure devops extension api

Tags: azure, azure-devops

How can I get the pipeline Id of the current release using azure-devops-extension-api? Is there any way to get the pipeline Id on current release page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Azure Devops API,

[`List Definitions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get all the recent releases and then [`Get Definition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to extract the details

Answer (score 0):

> How to get the pipeline Id of the current release in azure devops extension api

The azure-devops-extension-api package provide a Class [ReleaseRestClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-api/releaserestclient?view=azdevops-ext-latest#methods), which including a method [getReleases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-devops-extension-api/releaserestclient?view=azdevops-ext-latest#getreleases-string--number--number--string--string--releasestatus--number--date--date--releasequeryorder--number--number--releaseexpands--string--string--string--string--boolean--string----string----number----string-) to get a list of releases:

```
function getReleases(project?: string, definitionId?: number, definitionEnvironmentId?: number, searchText?: string, createdBy?: string, statusFilter?: ReleaseStatus, environmentStatusFilter?: number, minCreatedTime?: Date, maxCreatedTime?: Date, queryOrder?: ReleaseQueryOrder, top?: number, continuationToken?: number, expand?: ReleaseExpands, artifactTypeId?: string, sourceId?: string, artifactVersionId?: string, sourceBranchFilter?: string, isDeleted?: boolean, tagFilter?: string[], propertyFilters?: string[], releaseIdFilter?: number[], path?: string)
```

We could provide the Parameters `project`, `definitionId` to get the the pipeline Id of the current release.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking for the current successfully deployed pipeline ID on a particular stage. Say you are running your commands as part of a task in dev stage and you need the latest successfully deployed pipeline ID on dev stage.

There are two ways of getting the current release ID:

1. with every release definition, there is a current release updated in every environment in that release definition.

code Snippet:

```
releases = r_client_v4_1.get_release_definition(project='XXXXX', definition_id=id)
for env in releases.environments:
    if env.name == "dev":
        print(env.additional_properties["currentRelease"]["id"])
```

Issue with this is, the currentRelease get updated even with the active running release. As you are running this script in a release pipeline, that present deploying release will be listed as current Release. If you need the successfully deployed release ID then you can use second approach.

2. In this approach, you can go to the history of deployments and then get the successfully deployed release ID.

Code Snippet:

```
history = r_client_v4_1.get_deployments(project="XXXXX", definition_id=release_definition_id,
                                        definition_environment_id=release_env_definition_id,
                                        deployment_status="Succeeded", latest_attempts_only=True, top=1)

rel_ids.append(str(history[0].release.id))
```

This will give you the current successfully deployed release ID.

Note: Code is in python using the azure-devops library

Recently I have been in a similar situation as I was trying to find out the delta of changes between the current deployed release vs the present deploying release during deployment.